# riddle? MYSQL - LIMIT in subquery using JOIN. Want to delete all posts except minimum 100 posts per category but some posts in several categories

Tags: mysql, wordpress, join, subquery, limit

Hi for wordpress with mysql8 (8.0.23):

I want to delete all posts except a minimum of 100 posts per category.
So on the frontend, I want any category clicked to show a minimum of 100 posts.

This seems easy except many posts exist in more than one category.

So for category A, if I delete all posts >100, post row number 112 might also exist in category B, but is only post row 80, and therefore gets deleted.

see the riddle?

so using 4 categories in a test, how can I

- delete category A posts >100
- but not <100 in category B
- but not <100 in category C
- but not <100 in category D

For this example below, categories A,B,C,D have IDs (71,72,73,74) which is using LIMIT in a subquery (had to use JOIN because LIMIT is not allowed in a subquery?)

```sql
SELECT * FROM wp_posts
 
    JOIN 
    (
        SELECT ID 
        FROM wp_posts 
        WHERE NOT 
        (wp_posts.ID IN ( SELECT object_id FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (72) ) ) 
        LIMIT 100
    ) d
    ON wp_posts.ID 
    IN (d.ID)
    
    JOIN 
       (
        SELECT ID 
        FROM wp_posts 
        WHERE NOT 
        (wp_posts.ID IN ( SELECT object_id FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (73) ) ) 
         LIMIT 100
         ) e
        ON wp_posts.ID 
        IN (e.ID)
   
    JOIN 
       (
        SELECT ID 
        FROM wp_posts 
        WHERE NOT 
        (wp_posts.ID IN ( SELECT object_id FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (74) ) ) 
         LIMIT 100
         ) f
        ON wp_posts.ID 
        IN (f.ID)

 
  WHERE 
        (wp_posts.ID IN ( SELECT object_id FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (71) ) ) 
        AND (wp_posts.post_type = 'post' ) 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT 99999999
OFFSET 100
```

it comes up with zero rows

help appreciated!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION();` report? Folks who answer this may want to know if you can use window functions.

Comment: @BillKarwin oh its MySQL 8.0.23

Comment: add a row_number window function and partion it b< catgory but you still need an order by, when have the select and the rows till hunderd show your wanted result you can join it in the delete where you delete al with rn Y> 100

Comment: @nbk ahh so ```ROW_NUMBER() OVER``` is the alternative to using ```LIMIT```. Great will research how to do it :)

Comment: @nbk I am stuggling with wrapping row_number in main query.   
    `SELECT *  
    FROM  wp_posts  
       WHERE  
    wp_posts.ID IN  
    (SELECT * FROM (  
      SELECT  
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC) AS rownumber  
          FROM wp_posts  
      WHERE (wp_posts.ID IN (SELECT object_id FROM wp_term_relationships 
    WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (71) ) )  
    AND (wp_posts.post_type = 'post' OR wp_posts.post_type = 'xdays1')  
    ) AS foo  
    WHERE rownumber >= 100) `  
  
this only returns 10 rows, but the sub query returns 29,000 rows

Comment: please never post any code in coments it is unreadable.  Also your Row_number has only a order by date, but it needs also a `PaRTITION BY` that is the category you want hundreds from

Comment: @nbk managed to get it working without need for "partition by", thanks to a similar question I asked in stackflow specifically about ```ROW_NUMBER() OVER```. See answer below. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it.. but not using LIMIT with JOIN.

Thanks to @nbk 's comment I am using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER` instead. This is allowed in a subquery. I have it here as a "select" statement instead of delete (for testing).

Using four categories here with category IDs 71,72,73 and 74.

```
SELECT wp_posts.*
FROM  wp_posts 
   
WHERE 

(wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')   
   
AND

-- posts discluded if under 100 most recent per category:
(

( wp_posts.ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM (SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC) AS rownumber
  FROM wp_posts
  WHERE (wp_posts.ID IN (SELECT object_id FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (71) ) ) 
AND (wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')  
) AS foo
WHERE rownumber <= 100
) 
)

AND

( wp_posts.ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM (SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC) AS rownumber
  FROM wp_posts
  WHERE (wp_posts.ID IN (SELECT object_id FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (72) ) ) 
AND (wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')  
) AS foo
WHERE rownumber <= 100
) 
)

AND

( wp_posts.ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM (SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC) AS rownumber
  FROM wp_posts
  WHERE (wp_posts.ID IN (SELECT object_id FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (73) ) ) 
AND (wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')  
) AS foo
WHERE rownumber <= 100
) 
)

AND

( wp_posts.ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM (SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC) AS rownumber
  FROM wp_posts
  WHERE (wp_posts.ID IN (SELECT object_id FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (74) ) ) 
AND (wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')  
) AS foo
WHERE rownumber <= 100
) 
)

)
```